# Kafka Streams Create Time vs Log-Append Time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

If the Kafka broker is configured with `Log-Append Time`, will the broker overwrite the message timestamp regardless of the timestamp set by the producer/stream?

From [streams-time - Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/33/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_time), I get the impression that `CreateTime` is somewhat unreliable - the timestamp is sometimes only forwarded (e.g. when using `context.forward()`) and sometimes overwritten (e.g. when using `puntuate()`). I am therefore wondering if the `Log-Append Time` takes precedence when setting the message timestamp (i.e. overwrites the timestamp set by the stream)?

Comment: What have you tried to test your theory?

Comment: I haven't tried anything... I was hoping to find something in the docs, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: To my knowledge, both methods you've referred to create a new output topic, and does not modify any records of the original topic. I believe the last cluster I used was using LogAppend time and we never had issues with timestamps set in the producers. In any case, records are immutable once in the topic, so timestamps shouldn't be modified, anyway

Comment: The question was meant for new messages, yes! Sorry for my lack of precision. Based on your experience I'm tempted to conclude that `Log-Append Time` takes precedence :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean "takes precedence" when I am saying that the timestamp the consumer sees is the one that the producer had introduced, either by manually setting in the ProducerRecord or via the default constructor, not when the record arrived at the broker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `LogAppendTime` takes precedence, meaning if the topic is configured to use `LogAppendTime`, the timestamp set by the Streams application (no matter how it is generated) will be ignored and overwritten with the log append time by the broker when the output record is produced.

Furthermore, I don't think `CreateTime` is unreliable in the way you think. `punctuate()` doesn't overwrite an existing timestamp - it is used to generate a fresh record at a specific point in time, so there is no previous `CreateTime` available - Streams must pick a new timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc of the ProducerRecord class](https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html) confirms that `LogAppendTime` takes precedence:

> If the topic is configured to use LogAppendTime, the timestamp in the producer record will be overwritten by the broker with the broker local time when it appends the message to its log.